# how to create a separate master page and publish it for a sub site without changing the master page in sp2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need help to create a master page for the master page for a subsite.
Without interfering the main site.
And also need help to publish it .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <!-- This template was included in a design course that was written, designed, developed, and recorded by Chris Converse -->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta id="view" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Creating A Responsive Web Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_layout_large.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px)"   href="css/screen_layout_small.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:800px)"  href="css/screen_layout_medium.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
        </header>

        <article>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="#">Duis aute irure</a> dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </article>

        <div class="promo_container">

            <div class="promo one">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                    <p><a class="cta" href="">Visit our blog</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="promo two">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                    <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit est laborum.</p>
                    <p><a class="cta" href="">Read the article</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="promo three">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor inci did unt.</p>
                    <p><a class="cta" href="">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear-fix"></div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <footer>
            &copy; Your Organization Name
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a sample one. I am trying to add the similar code.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score -1):

1. go to site settings --> master pages and page layouts (/_catalogs/masterpages/).

   select master page (like oslo.aspx) --> open menu and select download a copy
2. edit the page and rename
3. upload the new page to masterpage gallery (like step 1)
   go to a top ribbon 'fiels' and click 'checkIn' and also click 'publish'
4. go to site settings in your sub site --> master page
   check radio: 'specify a master page...'
   select the new master page from list 
   and check: 'restart all sub sites...'
   click ok